# Angular custom UI based on ASP.NET MVC claims values

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, authentication, jwt

I am currently migrating an ASP.NET MVC razor app to Angular. I already had claims managed by ASP.NET. Token is generated server side, assigned to response cookie and stored on client localstorage.

Razor was able to access the claims with ease, but since I am separating UI from backend, I had to find a way of accessing user claims in different approach.

I came up with a solution of exposing an endpoint that returns current user claim. Simple no param endpoint, returns claim that is decrypted from a valid token.

If claims are returned, then I can trust that user has a valid token.
On angular side I simply his that endpoint from an authService, which is injected in each pages constructor and endpoint is hit on each page refresh.

Is that any of good solution?

Comment: I think that's the only solution, as only the backend would be able to extract the claims.  You might just hit it once and store the values in session cookies or state so you don't have to hit it on every request.  Or just let the backend set session cookies on login that is httponly=false.  Your front-end can read that.  (There's no reason to protect this since it will only determine the view.)

Comment: after further reading, I think I was a bit wrong there.  JWT claims aren't necessarily encrypted... the claims themselves are not secret.  The only thing that is required to be secret is the key they were signed with.... they usually have a public key the server uses to validate the SIGNATURE of the JWT that is generated with the identity providers private key.... so it's really only the server that can validate the signature.  You can usually extract the claims client-side, but not validate the signature.

Comment: (correction: you can validate client-side using the public key) You could share the public key with the front end as that is also not secret, but you shouldn't really need to validate since the backend actions are usually the only things that need to be secured.  I found a little utility here for decoding the claims which are usually just Base64 endoded: https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode